# ANDing props in bean ctor

Tags: spring

Is it possible for properties to be ANDed in XML or bean construction? Something like:

```
<constructor-arg value="${walks.like.a.duck} && ${talks.like.a.duck}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Spring 3 you can do that, see the [documentation for Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html). The operator is `and`, not `&&`. It should look like:

```
<constructor-arg value="${walks.like.a.duck} and ${talks.like.a.duck}"/>
```